# Compiler error using loops, switch and case

Tags: java, animation, compiler-errors, switch-statement, case

I've animated my some of my program, it's a guy moving, and it works and everything.  I have a lot of repeating code though so I wanted to try and make it more efficient and loop through what's repeating.  My problem is that even with the right amount of brackets it gives me errors for almost everything below

```
      public void DrawAstronaut(Graphics2D g2d) {
    if (nViewDX == -1) {
        DrawAstronautLeft(g2d);
    } else if (nViewDX == 1) {
        DrawAstronautRight(g2d);
    } else {
        DrawAstronautStand(g2d);
    }
}

public void DrawAstronautLeft(Graphics2D g2d) {
    switch (nAstroAnimPos) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
        case i:
            g2d.drawImage(arimgAstroWalkLeft[i], nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
            break;
        default:
            g2d.drawImage(imgAstroStandLeft, nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
            break;
        }
}
}
    public void DrawAstronautRight(Graphics2D g2d) {
    switch (nAstroAnimPos) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++){
        case i:
            g2d.drawImage(arimgAstroWalkRight[i], nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1,                                               this);
            break;
        default:
            g2d.drawImage(imgAstroStandRight, nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void DrawAstronautStand(Graphics2D g2d) {
    switch (nAstroAnimPos) {
        default:
            g2d.drawImage(imgAstroStandLeft, nAstronautX, nAstronautY, this);
            break;
}
}
```

When I added the for loop to the DrawAstronautLeft everything below got errors, it didn't even like the public void DrawAstronautRight even though their shouldn't be anything wrong with it.  I know I have the right amount of brackets but could someone help put things in the right place?

The Errors Include:
Not being able to find symbols
"case, default, or "}" expected"
"class, interface, or enum expected"

Comment: Always copy/paste error & exception output.  I'd think you need the loop surrounding the entire switch statement.

Comment: Your `switch-case` is redundant.. Well.. it's always `i`....

Comment: So putting the switch in the for loop got rid of all the errors every except in the "case i:", thanks @AndrewThompson

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun are you saying that because of my loop I no longer need the switch?

Comment: @BlueBarren Because when you `switch(i)`, the case is **always** `i`. When you fix it, it won't be redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need switch. You can just modify your loop with-

```
for(int i = 0; i <= nAstroAnimPos; i++){
    if(i == 0) // Start with stand position
        g2d.drawImage(imgAstroStandLeft, nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
    else // Run the sequence from 1 to 6
        g2d.drawImage(arimgAstroWalkLeft[i], nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);    
}
```

If you want to end with also stand position-

```
for(int i = 0; i <= nAstroAnimPos + 1; i++){
    if(i == 0 || i == nAstroAnimPos + 1) // Start and end with stand position
        g2d.drawImage(imgAstroStandLeft, nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);
    else // Run the sequence from 1 to 6
        g2d.drawImage(arimgAstroWalkLeft[i], nAstronautX + 1, nAstronautY + 1, this);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful.  I don't know if it works yet because the way I've loaded my images into an array isn't working but I'm sure when I fix that it will! ^.^